# Website using angular js and firebase Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: jquery, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble with my angular js, it will give me this error [print screen of the error in the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF5Ls.png)

I'm trying to retrieve the users name through firebase and then I'd print it onto the webpage using angular js.

this is my code inside my html

```
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">

            <!--<h1 id="homeHeading">Your Favorite Source of Free Bootstrap Themes</h1>!-->
            <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">//fix this

                <p>welcome, {{firstname}}</p>
                <hr>
                <p>Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap CSS framework! Just download your template and start going, no strings attached!</p>
                <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

and this one is my javascript

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
            var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

            console.log(userId);
            $scope.firstname = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
                console.log(snapshot.val().firstname);
                return snapshot.val().firstname;
            });
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
            if(firebaseUser){
                console.log(firebaseUser);
            }else{
                window.location.replace("index.html");
                console.log('not logged in');
            }
        });
        $("#btnLogout").click(function(){
            firebase.auth().signOut();
            window.location.replace("index.html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your javascript code is incomplete. Did you miss something on top? At the end are closing brackets, which produce an error.

Comment: I didn't add all my javascript code because the rest is just irrelevant firebase stuff

Comment: I don't need the firebase stuff. The problem is, your code works perfectly (if I remove the last brackets of course). So I actually can't help you without more of your code. My guess is, that your angular.module is not getting called.

Comment: oh okok I'll edit my post, and give you the full javascript.

Comment: still new to js but is my syntax alright now? I'm still getting the same error with my angular js but no syntax error

Comment: Yep, syntax is fine now. See my answer for your working code

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're calling angular.module on document ready. Document ready, obviously, get's called after angular looks for your module.

Working javascript:

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
            var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

            console.log(userId);
            $scope.firstname = firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
                console.log(snapshot.val().firstname);
                return snapshot.val().firstname;
            });
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
            if(firebaseUser){
                console.log(firebaseUser);
            }else{
                window.location.replace("index.html");
                console.log('not logged in');
            }
        });
        $("#btnLogout").click(function(){
            firebase.auth().signOut();
            window.location.replace("index.html");
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added **ngRoute**. add this code and check again.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: @Mr. Munchkin Try this solution, this will help you.

Comment: have you added link in your index.html file?

Comment: yea, the javascript is actually inside my html, I was planning on cleaning it up later when I fix the bugs, because I'm lazy lol